# JavaScript Promises and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have been playing with Promises, but I am having trouble understanding what is happening with the following code:

```
function a() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        resolve("hi from a!");
    });
}

function b() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        setTimeout(function () { 
            resolve("hi from b!");
        }, 5000);
    });
}

function c() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        setTimeout(function () { 
            resolve("hi from c!");
        }, 1000);
    });
}

a().then(function (resultFromA) {
    console.log("a() responded with: " + resultFromA);
    b();
}).then(function (resultFromB) { 
    console.log("b() responded with: " + resultFromB);
    c();
}).then(function (resultFromC) { 
    console.log("c() responded with: " + resultFromC);
});
```

I am expecting this to output `a() responded with: hi from a!` immediately, along with `b() responded with: hi from b!` and `c() responded with: hi from c!` after their respective `setTimeout()` fires. However, what I get this the following output immediately:

> a() responded with: hi from a!
>
> b() responded with: undefined
>
> c() responded with: undefined

I was thinking that `.then()` waits on these promises, but it isn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `return b()` and `return c()` from within your `then` handlers.

`then` only "replaces" the first promise with a subsequent promise which is **returned** from its callback.

If your `then` callback doesn't `return` a promise, then the `then` applies to the original promise, and it will be executed immediately regardless of the contents/result of the previous `then` callback.

Basically...

```
a().then(function () {
  b()
}).then( # This "then" is chained off of a's promise
```

While conversely:

```
a().then(function () {
  return b()
}).then( # This "then" is chained off of b's promise
```

Comment: This explanation isn't right. The` then()` function always returns a new promise. However, in the case above (`b()`) the return value of the function is `undefined`, which is wrapped in a new Promise. It looks like the second promise is chained off the `a()` promise because the body of the `.then()` function completes synchronously, so the then completes immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `return promises` to chain them :

```
a().then(function (resultFromA) {
  console.log("a() responded with: " + resultFromA);
  // return b() promise
  return b();
}).then(function (resultFromB) { 
  console.log("b() responded with: " + resultFromB);
  // return c() promise
  return c();
}).then(function (resultFromC) { 
  console.log("c() responded with: " + resultFromC);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to return from function call. Javascript function does not return implicitly.

```
function a() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        resolve("hi from a!");
    });
}

function b() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        setTimeout(function () { 
            resolve("hi from b!");
        }, 5000);
    });
}

function c() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        setTimeout(function () { 
            resolve("hi from c!");
        }, 1000);
    });
}

a().then(function (resultFromA) {
    console.log("a() responded with: " + resultFromA);
    return b(); // return 
}).then(function (resultFromB) { 
    console.log("b() responded with: " + resultFromB);
    return c(); // return
}).then(function (resultFromC) { 
    console.log("c() responded with: " + resultFromC);
});
```

Comment: My issue was that for some reason I thought that the `then` waits on all Promises in the local scope to resolve, when it really was only the one that gets `return`ed. I originally wasn't trying to do `return b()` or `return c()`.

Comment: "Javascript function does not return implicitly."
Not entirely true. Arrow functions *do* return implicitly, when the body is a single expression: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body